# Is it passible to make a Chrome Extension work as a backend?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I have this project that I want to explore it is possibility and see if it is possible to get it done.

So I have one website that has a Chrome extension = Users install this Chrome extension to automate some tasks (Working- Current Status)

I want to give users the option to automate these tasks for them in the backend on my server. (What I want to get built)

In short: I have the automation already done, but the user must install the Chrome extension and do it by hand.
I want to automate this part on the server. so we automate (the Chrome extension work).

So my idea is to host this Chrome extension on my server, then using API we receive requests from my website, then do the automation, and then send the results/status back to the website.

I was reading that using Selenium or some automation library and then loading this Chrome extension to each instance of the browser then doing this automation, but don't know if it is possible.

is this possibele? any tips is really appreciated

I have the chrome extention done working fine on client side.

Comment: Extensions run only inside the browser. They can exchange data with your server by making network requests.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm aware of that. Will handle the connection between my server and the extension using API calls and network requests, as you said. However my idea comes beacuse  In selenium for example you can load an extension for each browser instance.

Comment: The only thing "backendy" about chrome extensions is that you can make requests that ignore cors. You can always make requests to a backend from the extension though.

Comment: @pguardiario so, theoretically it is possible right?

Comment: @N4d - Sure, I've done it before. You can even send their cookies to the backend, scrape things with puppeteer and send them back in the response.

Comment: @pguardiario Awesome and great to hear. I couldn't find any resources online for such tasks which gave me some doubts of the possibility of it. If you have any resources please share.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Puppeteer for this. You can create non-headless browser instances on your server and then install your extensions to created browser instances. [Puppeteer with Chrome extension](https://pptr.dev/guides/chrome-extensions)